# Hosteando Web Services

Tags: c#, webservice

Estoy tratando de hostear un web services en un hosting que contraté. Lo utilizo para logueo de usuario, y sólo tiene que validar usuario y contraseña

Desde Visual Studio creé un proyecto web vacío. Le agregue un archivo `.asmx`, y cuando lo publico subo `WS.asmx` y `Web.config`.

El `Web.Config` contiene:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>

</configuration>
```

El problema es que al ejecutarlo me tira el siguiente error

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list
> the contents of this directory.
>
> Most likely causes:
> A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.
>
> Things you can try: If you do not want to enable directory browsing,
> ensure that a default document is configured and that the file exists.
> Enable directory browsing using IIS Manager. Open IIS Manager. In the
> Features view, double-click Directory Browsing. On the Directory
> Browsing page, in the Actions pane, click Enable. Verify that the
> configuration/system.webServer/directoryBrowse@enabled attribute is
> set to true in the site or application configuration file.

Comment: "*al ejecutarlo me tira el siguiente error*" <-- ¿Cómo lo estás ejecutando?

Comment: Primero que nada, ¿Como quieres hacerlo? SOAP o rest??

Comment: Desde la URL del servidor

Comment: @AlejandroRicotti y estás incluyendo `WS.asmx` en esa URL?

Comment: @AlejandroRicotti creo que te falta leer mucha teoria, porque existen 3 tipos de webservice xml-rpc que ya casi no se usa, Webservice SOAP y Webservice rest. La forma que mencionas no corresponde con la creación de ninguno de ellos, por eso te preguntaba como querías hacerlo, ya que ningun webService es hecho para invocarse desde el navegador, aunque puedes ver respuestas en el browser, ese no es el objetivo

Comment: @abrahamhs Si en realidad solo quería abrirlo desde el navegador para probarlo, ya pude meterlo en mi aplicacion y hacerlo funcionar, solo que nunca había hosteado uno y no estaba seguro como funcionaba pero ya pude solucionarlo, gracias!

Comment: ok, para probarlo puedes usar un software llamado SOAP UI, en el puedes probar web service soap o rest, y te muestra toda la estructura del mensaje

Comment: @AlejandroRicotti si has solucionado tu problema, podrías autorresponder tu pregunta a fin de que otros puedan beneficiarse de tu experiencia.

Comment: @ElAsiduo Si perdón. Hay que ir a Visual Studio, poner Add Reference y poner la dirección del hosting y la pagina con extension .asmx donde esta nuestro servicio, también se debería poder acceder desde el navegador aunque no es la idea

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas agregar la referencia del servicio para poder usarlo en el proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]